# How can I get the total value count of the next two rows of rows that have more than one same value in a column?

Tags: python

I want to get the total value count of the next two rows of rows that have more than one same value in a column.

I have a `.csv` file as follows:

| Alphabet | Sub alphabet | Value |
| --- | --- | --- |
| A | B | 1 |
| A | C | 2 |
| D | B | 3 |
| D | C | 4 |

When I return the result for the letter A, I want it to return a number like this (1 + 2):

```
3
```

When I return the result for the letter D, I want it to return a number like this (3 + 4):

```
7
```

When I return to all the letters, I hope it will return to such a list:

```
['A: 3', 'D: 7']
```

My code:

```
import csv

with open("/Users/name/Desktop/path/alphabetical_list.csv") as alphabetical_list_file:
    csv_reader = csv.reader(alphabetical_list_file, delimiter=',')
```

Feel free to leave a comment if you need more information.

How can I get the total value count of the next two rows of rows that have more than one same value in a column? I would appreciate any help. Thank you in advance!

Comment: The [`csv` docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html) tells you how to iterate over rows and get values.

Comment: Hi @Ouroborus thanks for your comment. Can you answer this question and share the code? I'm not very good at the Python programming language and I'm not sure how to do this by referencing that csv document

Comment: @Ouroborus also, what I want is not just to iterate through the rows and get the values, I need to add all the values of the same alphabet

Comment: @MyCar - Sorry, I was out of town and I just noticed your request for me to look at this. Although, my answer would have been the same as the one you accepted.

Comment: Hi @OneMadGypsy, it's ok

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is quite easily done using [pandas](/questions/tagged/pandas):

```
import pandas as pd

out = (pd.read_csv('your_file.csv', sep=',')
         .groupby('Alphabet')['Value']
         .apply(lambda g: f'{g.name}: {g.sum()}')
         .tolist()
       )
```

Or:

```
import pandas as pd

out = [f'{name}: {g.sum()}' for name, g in
       pd.read_csv('your_file.csv', sep=',').groupby('Alphabet')['Value']]
```

Output:

```
['A: 3', 'D: 7']
```

Comment: Hi thanks for your answer! Your answer code works! Thanks again!